# charater utf8mb3 is not supported by .NET framework

Tags: mysql-workbench, visual-studio-2022, character-set

The following message pops up when I start my C# desktop app in VS-2022 and keeps popping up at various other times but the application appears to work notmally otherwise.

**Character utf8mb3 is not supported by .net framework**

I am connected to a MySql database which uses utf8mb4 as it's default character set for tables where applicable. Why do I get this message and how can I suppress it since the application otherwise runs as expected? The difficulty I am having is that most discussions on this issue I find are extremely above my level of expertise, when it appears to me to be a trivial issue but very annoying issue. plese help

I have not been able to find anything that I can try except making sure that all tables and columns in my database have MySql specified character sets, namely utf8mb4.